# What's the minimum number of players to start a Gardens & Graveyards game in PvZ Garden Warfare?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare

I joined a server of Classic Gardens & Graveyards and there weren't many people. There was the guy on the Zombie team and I was the plant. It still showed "Waiting for players". Can't two players start the game and have some fun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I discovered this finally the hard way. It's 4.